# How to obtain the blank fields for given item number?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

For given item code in pt_mstr , i want all fields which are blank for that record of item code.

Can you help me to write the code for that above problem

Comment: Obtain a handle for the record in pt_mstr, and then iterate through the fields in the record, and report the field name for those that fields that have no value. The manual for buffer and buffer-field will tell you how to do this.

Comment: hi @Screwtape , can you plz send me the code for this program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hBuffer AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE i       AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hField  AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN hBuffer = BUFFER pt_mstr:HANDLE .

DO i = 1 TO hBuffer:NUM-FIELDS:

    ASSIGN hField = hBuffer:BUFFER-FIELD (i) .

    IF hField:DATA-TYPE = "CHARACTER" AND (hField:BUFFER-VALUE = "" OR hField:BUFFER-VALUE = ?) THEN 
        MESSAGE hField:NAME "is empty"
            VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX. 

END.
```

If there are arrays you'll have to iterate them based on hField:EXTENT and use hField:BUFFER-VALUE[j] to access the field value.

Comment: hi @Mike Fenchner , i want blank fields for given item number, mean if i enter item number something i want for blank fields for that record only

Comment: In that case, you have to FIND the record with that item number first.

Comment: Is it big change in that program for that? @Mike Fechner can you write how?

Comment: I believe pt_mstr is MFG/pro - and I don't have an MFG/pro instance at hand. But adding a FIND for that record is very basic ABL programming.... Just add FIND pt_mstr WHERE <keyfieldname> = <youritemnumber> before the ASSIGN hBuffer = BUFFER pt_mstr_HANDLE statement.

Comment: Thanks @Mike Fechner it's working now. I want one more help from you those fields i want to display in one frame say first five fields and to upadate the fields in that frame only. is it possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible. But since the list of fields is dynamic/dependent on data this would require a good amount of dynamic coding.

Comment: Can we get the blank fields for an item number without using buffer?is it possible

Comment: Can we get the blank fields for an item number without using buffer?is it possible @sherbang

Comment: In ABL all data access is using buffers.